# Can't get rid of a Rails warning: "multiple values for a block parameter (0 for 1)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, warnings

I'm getting these warnings:

```
payment_method.rb:11: warning: multiple values for a block parameter (0 for 1)
payment_method.rb:12: warning: multiple values for a block parameter (0 for 1)
```

payment_method.rb lines 11 and 12:

```
class PaymentMethod < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  named_scope :expiring_next_month, lambda {|pm| {:conditions => {:ed => DateTime.now.beginning_of_month}}}
  named_scope :expired, lambda {|pm| {:conditions => ["ed < ?", DateTime.now.beginning_of_month]}}
  ...
end
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a params on your scope. You need use it. Or not define it

```
named_scope :expiring_next_month, lambda { {:conditions => {:ed => DateTime.now.beginning_of_month}}}
named_scope :expired, lambda { {:conditions => ["ed < ?", DateTime.now.beginning_of_month]}}
```

With my case you can call without args. Not in your case. In ruby 1.8 there are no way to have optionnal params in lambda.